# Is there a way to increase the timeout with siesta framework

Tags: swift, httprequest, siesta-swift

I searched on the docs of siesta framework but I couldn't find a way to set a timeout for a http request. I need to set a longer timeout because I'm sending a http request to a very slow web service and I receive a timeout error from the framework. I know I can configure the timeout NSURLSessionConfiguration, but I need to increase the timeout only for certain endpoints, not for every request

Comment: AFAIK Siesta doesnt handle the requests by itself. It uses other frameworks for that (`NSURLSession` by default but you can use something like `Alamofire` if you want, or [any other library](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/NetworkingProvider.html)). So the question should really be about _that_ library and not Siesta (btw I can see that Siesta's configuration includes an [`expirationTime`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Structs/Configuration.html#/s:6Siesta13ConfigurationV14expirationTimeSdv), have you checked that?)

Comment: Yes, I checked expirationTime, but it's about cache duration for GET http requests